# Where to find "Incumbent party margin of victory data"?

Tags: dataset, elections

In [Which Economic Indicators Best Predict Presidential Elections?](http://fivethirtyeight.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/11/18/which-economic-indicators-best-predict-presidential-elections/), Nate Silver references a variable called "Incumbent Party Margin of Victory" for US presidential elections.  I was wondering, is there a free source for this data?

Comment: Perhaps you could email Nate Silver (nrsilver@gmail.com) and ask him yourself?  That blog contains an email link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For presidential elections, check out [David Leip's Atlas of U.S. Presidential Elections](http://uselectionatlas.org/). I'm not sure how much he gives away for free, but it's a rich resource.

You might also be interested in the [data set](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/rep/RDReplication.zip) used in Caughey and Sekhon (2011). A data appendix is provided in the [web appendix of the paper](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/papers/RDappendix.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, that's a fascinating dataset.  However, I'm specifically interested in presidential elections.

Comment: Right, of course, sorry about that. You might try the resource that I added in an edit.